# Blender 2.9: hollow cylinder has "Normals" problem

Tags: normals

I want to make a cannon and I am using a hollow cylinder for that. But as soon as I create it, I am seeing an issue with the normals.

[image]

I can flip the normals but then the inside faces are blue and the outside faces are red. The same when I try to recalculate the normals.

How can I fix the normals so the faces are blue on the outside and inside?

Thank you for your help,
Peter

Comment: Hello :). You need to add new faces to the inside. *Solidify modifier* should be a fast and easy solution :).

Comment: thank you Michal, I will try that tonight.

Comment: Hi Michal, it works perfectly with the Solidify modifier. Thank you so much!